# Vue adding condition to @click event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a bootstrap collapse and I want to perform a fetch of data when you open the collapse but not when you close it. So I need to perform a check on the `aria-expanded` attribute.

I am not sure if this is a good approach, because this will always perform the fetch, on close and on open.

```
<span
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#collapseExample"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-controls="collapseExample"
>
    <small @click="fetch(id)">Open/Close</small>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your logic in the fetch method to check if the data is already loaded. Add a new dictionary to the data() and add the details to the `fetchedData`.

```
data() {
  return {
    fetchedData: {}
  }
},
methods: {
   fetch: function(id) {
       if(this.fetchedData[id]) {
          return this.fetchedData[id];
       } else {
          // call to fetch the data and add those details to the dictionary fetchedData
          this.fetchedData[id] = response.data;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: well this is actually what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: any specific reason to avoid this?

Comment: because this little snippet of code happens in a loop, that's where the (id) come from.

Comment: ok. let the id come from a loop, I don't see any problem with that. your intention is to make an API call to fetch the data if it is opened right? let's consider this scenario, If a user has closed and opened twice and if you have logic to fetch the data only on the open this would again make a second API call to fetch data that is already available.